# TomekLinks fit_sample(X,y) taking huge time

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, imblearn

I am working on a text classification problem. I am using TomekLinks class of imblearn module to resample my data.But after calling fit_sample(X,y) method of TomekLinks class program does nothing even if i wait for 30 mins.
My data set is 1800000 records long(text data).Here is the code snippet

from imblearn.under_sampling import TomekLinks

tl = TomekLinks(return_indices=True, ratio='majority',random_state=42)
X_tl, y_tl = tl.sample(train_x,y_binary)

Can anyone help as why it is taking such a long time?

Also when i do tl.fit() seperately it completes within seconds , but when i call tl.sample() method , error is raised that there is no attribute named sample in TomekLinks